# Count if 2 columns say same value Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

hi iam pretty new to excel and would like some help

I want to add up numbers that have yes in BOTH columns

```
2   yes yes
3   yes yes
4   yes yes
3   no  yes
5   yes yes
6   yes no
```

i know how to do 1 column =COUNTIF(B2:B5,"Yes") 
how do i do it that it checks if both columns have yes
so the answer should be 14

Thanks

Comment: How do you get `14`? At best I could see `10`...

Comment: total of the number of the value is 23 and 2 columns with no equals to 9. so 23-9=14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMIFS()`:

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A6,B1:B6,"yes",C1:C6,"yes")
```